# Characterize the generators of the totally real subfield of an arbitrary cyclotomic field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Suppose that K = $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta )$ where $\zeta $ is a primitive nth root of unity, then the matching totally real subfield is ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +\text{ }1/\zeta )$ . (These two have ‘matching’ rings of integers given by $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta ]$ and   $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta +1/\zeta ]$ .)

So the ‘canonical’ generator of ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ is $\zeta +1/\zeta ={{\lambda }_{n}}=2\operatorname{Cos}(2\pi /n)$ which has minimal degree $\varphi (n)/2$ for n > 2, but any Galois conjugate of ${{\lambda }_{n}}$ would suffice so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +1/\zeta )=\mathbb{Q}({{\zeta }^{k}}+1/{{\zeta }^{k}})$  for gcd(k,n) = 1. The question is how to characterize the possible generators of ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ .

For example ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /n)$ will always be a generator of ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ based on the ‘double-angle’ formula relating cos and tan. There are other possible candidates including any algebraic integer a in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta + 1/\zeta ]$. Note that ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /n)$ is not an algebraic integer when n is twice-odd (a case that some authors omit). For example ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /6)$ is 1/3 but here ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ which is also $\mathbb{Q}(1/3)$ . It can be awkward doing calculations with non-integer generators, and there are often advantages to using unit generators. Even ${{\lambda }_{n}}$ sometimes fails here. For example ${{\lambda }_{12}}$ =$\sqrt{3}$  which is the ‘canonical’ choice of generator but it is not a unit and ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /12)$ = $7-4\sqrt{3}$  is a unit which can be used as an alternate generator of ${{\text{K}}^{+}}$ for n =12. (Geometrically this ‘scaling parameter’ has the advantage of properly describing how generations of polygons scale relative to the dodecagon as ‘parent’.  For n = 6 above, this natural geometric scaling is the identity so in this case ${{\lambda }_{6}}$ = 1 is the correct scaling and ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /n)$  should only be used as an alternative generator when n is twice-even.)  The real issue is understanding what choices are possible and any help along these lines will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For $p$ prime thus for $n$ square-free the conjugates of $\zeta_n$ are a normal basis so it is simply

$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) = \sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times}\zeta_n^m \mathbb{Q},\qquad \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}) = \sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times/\{ \pm 1\}}(\zeta_n^m +\zeta_n^{-m}) \mathbb{Q}$$ $$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta),  \beta =\!\! \!\!\sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times/\{ \pm 1\}}\!\!\!\!(\zeta_n^m +\zeta_n^{-m}) b_m \iff \forall k \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times/\{ \pm 1\}, \exists m,  b_{mk} \ne b_m$$

Not sure if there is a way to enumerate the $\beta$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}]= \mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ other than enumerating the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}]$ and checking one by one

Comment: Thank you reuns for your input. I agree with your statements but I am still hoping that there might be a more practical way to characterize the generators. Maybe this is not realistic.

Comment: @sunshineghh If you mean the primitive elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})$ then (for $n$ square-free) you can't make more practical than what I wrote. $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times/\{ \pm 1\}$ is a product of cyclic groups.

Comment: I am not looking for a definition of generator but instead a characterization that could be used to identify or rule out candidates. As stated in the narrative any such characterization should apply to all cyclotomic fields - not just square free.

Comment: @sunshineghh ?? That's exactly what my answer is. Is your problem how to apply it to $\tan^2(\pi m/n)$ and any quotients ? Since the case $n$ square-free is easier looking first at it is a good idea.

Comment: @sunshineghh Sure being insulting is nonproductive. As you see I will be glad to help once you will be capable to say what you want..

Comment: I apologize reuns if my last comment offended you –I said earlier that I agreed with your answer but I was hoping for a more practical criteria. Jyrki Lahtonen also agrees with your answer and maybe it was not realistic to expect more. My thanks to both of you

Comment: @sunshineghh One thing which is not fully obvious in my answer is how to check if $\alpha=\tan^2(\pi m/n)$ or things like that (ie. quotients of linear combinations of $\cos(2\pi m/n)$) generates the field. If this is what you are asking, then the goal is to find if some element of the Galois group $\Bbb{Z/nZ}^\times / \pm 1$ acts trivially on $\alpha$. The 2nd problem is how to check if a given element generates the ring of integers, for this my guess is that you need to start from a concrete $\alpha,n$ and compute the index of $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\cos(2\pi/n)]$

Comment: Thank you for your interest. My goal is to show that ‘scales’of the form s1/sk with sk = tan(kPi/n) are generators of the maximal real subfield K+  when gcd(k,n) = 1 and k >1. It is not hard to show that these scales are integers - and also units, but the issue is showing that they have full index phi(n)/2. As a set they form a basis for K+ which is not a trivial fact. I really only need the smallest scales – which by symmetry are s1 squared for n twice-even and s1s2 for n twice-odd. I have proved that s1 must be degree phi(n)/2 and the sk are Galois conjugates so that should do it.

Comment: I just published a paper on arxiv that uses some of these results. It is at http://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09295. Thanks again for your help